# Circuit to select from 2 inputs 4-20mA and 0-10V

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, electrical

[image]

[image]

I want to select one from the 2 inputs.
if (BSP pressed) then
output=0-10V
else output=4-20mA.

I used an and gate based on PNP and NPN mosfet but it didn't work.
any suggestion plZ.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. What is 'BSP pressed'? Where are the two inputs in the schematics you provided? Where is the output? what does output 0-10V else 4-20mA?

Comment: @JackSoldano push button .I am looking for analog selector based on CMOS techn for examle. thank you for your comment I appreciate it

Comment: @B.walid there is no Net/Component in the schematic who is called BSP or looks like a push button to me. What is shown in circuit photo 1? What is shown in circuit photo 2? Please also answer the other questions Jack asked.